# AFNetworking/ Overcoat/Promisekit - getting the return json in the error message

Tags: objective-c, promise, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, promisekit

I am using AFNetworking, Overcoat and Promisekit. I  would like to see the json that I am getting back from the server.

```
//apiclient.h
@interface STRAPIClient : OVCHTTPSessionManager

//apiclient.m
[self POST:@"contents" parameters:parameters]
    .then(^(OVCResponse *response) {
      return response.result;
    })
    .catch(^(NSError * error){
        NSLog(error.description);
    });;
```

How do i get the response string from the NSError object?

Comment: What response are  you referring to? If the error corresponds to a network error then you'd have no response.

Comment: sorry, i clarified. i am referring to json string the server is returning

Answer (score 0):

Check `error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey]` and `error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey]`.

From `AFURLResponseSerialization.h`:

> #### Constants
>
> `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey`
>   The corresponding value is an `NSURLResponse` containing the response of the operation associated with an error. This key is only present in the `AFURLResponseSerializationErrorDomain`.
>
> `AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey`
>   The corresponding value is an `NSData` containing the original data of the operation associated with an error. This key is only present in the `AFURLResponseSerializationErrorDomain`.